# Getting a Content-Length error despite specifying content length when POSTing data to XML server

Tags: php, xml, post

I have a really strange error. I'm trying to POST data to an XML data using the following code:

`$url = "http://www.example.appspot.com/clients";

$post_string = "< client>

< id>< /id>

< lastName>ABCDE< /lastName>

< firstName>< /firstName>

< company>< /company>

< telephone>< /telephone>

< mobile>< /mobile>

< fax>< /fax>

< website>< /website>

< email>< /email>

< addressLine1>< /addressLine1>

< addressLine2>< /addressLine2>

< addressLine3>< /addressLine3>

< town>< /town>

< county>< /county>

< postcode>< /postcode>

< /client>";

$header  = "POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ". strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ". strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= $post_string;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);  `

But this returns this error:

Length Required
POST requests require a Content-length header.

(which is from curl_exec($ch))

And this the header data printed out (print $header):

POST HTTP/1.0 Content-type: text/xml Content-length: 381 < client> < id>< /id> < lastName>ABCDE< /lastName> < firstName>< /firstName> < company>< /company> < telephone>< /telephone> < mobile>< /mobile> < fax>< /fax> < website>< /website> < email>< /email> < addressLine1>< /addressLine1> < addressLine2>< /addressLine2> < addressLine3>< /addressLine3> < town>< /town> < county>< /county> < postcode>< /postcode> < /client>

Wondering how to solve this problem I've clearly specified the content length header?! Does anyone else have this problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) referencing `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`...

> A custom request method to use instead of "GET" or "HEAD" when doing a HTTP request. This is useful for doing "DELETE" or other, more obscure HTTP requests. Valid values are things like "GET", "POST", "CONNECT" and so on; i.e. **Do not enter a whole HTTP request line here**. For instance, entering "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" would be incorrect.

So, `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` option should be set only to `"POST"`.

I think you may want to instead convert that `$header` string to an array of headers pared with the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option, but do not include the top `POST` header.  And, do not include the `$post_string` in the headers either - that belongs in the request body.